# npm install EACCESS when try to install outside of home dir on linux

Tags: node.js, npm, errno

I installed node v 18 on linux.

if I try these commands in my home dir all works well:

`npm create svelte@latest my-app cd my-app npm install`

svelte is installed.

when I try same commands outside my home dir, i.e. in /media/web/www I receive this error when npm install:

`npm ERR! code 1`

`pnpm ERR! path /media/web/www/my-app/node_modules/esbuild`

`npm ERR! command failed`

`npm ERR! command sh -c -- node install.js`

`npm ERR! node:internal/errors:491`

`npm ERR!     ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);`

`npm ERR!     ^`

`npm ERR!`

`npm ERR! <ref *1> Error: spawnSync /media/web/www/my-app/node_modules/esbuild/bin/esbuild EACCES`

`npm ERR!     at Object.spawnSync (node:internal/child_process:1110:20)`

`npm ERR!     at spawnSync (node:child_process:871:24)`

`npm ERR!     at Object.execFileSync (node:child_process:914:15)`

`npm ERR!     at validateBinaryVersion (/media/web/www/my-app/node_modules/esbuild/install.js:96:28)`

`npm ERR!     at /media/web/www/my-app/node_modules/esbuild/install.js:283:5 {`

`npm ERR!   errno: -13,`

`npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',`

`npm ERR!   syscall: 'spawnSync /media/web/www/my-app/node_modules/esbuild/bin/esbuild',`

`npm ERR!   path: '/media/web/www/my-app/node_modules/esbuild/bin/esbuild',`

`npm ERR!   spawnargs: [ '--version' ],`

`npm ERR!   error: [Circular *1],`

`npm ERR!   status: null,`

`npm ERR!   signal: null,`

`npm ERR!   output: null,`

`npm ERR!   pid: 0,`

`npm ERR!   stdout: null,`

`npm ERR!   stderr: null`

`npm ERR! }`

`npm ERR!`

`npm ERR! Node.js v18.13.0`

Why? I really don't understand.

this is part of my config:

`prefix = "/usr"`

and global modules are in:

/usr/lib/node_modules

same for react in /media/web/www when try npm start:

`sh: /media/web/www/app-name/node_modules/.bin/react-scripts: Permission denied`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I find solution to my problem.

Partion outside my home dir was mounted as users,users permission. And this was the cause of permission denied. Use "defaults" instead